# Energy in magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation

If I have a magnet and an iron object, then the object would move towards the magnet, and the energy required to do so is stored in the magnet itself, but there can't simply be an infinite amount of energy, so do magnets eventually "run out" of magnetism, and where does the magnet get the energy from in the first place?